# how to expose component methods in render function in vue3 with ts

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-render-function

I want to call the child component methods in parent file and the child component is created by render function.
below is my code

child.ts

```js
export default {
  setup(props) {
    //...

    const getCropper = () => {
      return cropper
    }

    return () =>
      // render function
      h('div', { style: props.containerStyle }, [
      ])
  }
```

parent.ts

```js
<template>
 <child-node ref="child"></child-node>
</template>

<script>
export default defineComponent({
  setup(){
    const child =ref(null)
    
    // call child method
    child.value?.getCropper()


    return { child }
  }

})
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's TS-friendly way to do this. Consider opening an issue.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for your suggestions.I will try to do it.

Comment: I posted the way it can be done now, but afaik Vue won't handle types for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Component instance can be extended by using `expose`, this is useful for cases where `setup` return value is already render function:

```
type ChildPublicInstance = { getCropper(): void }
  ...
  setup(props: {}, context: SetupContext) {
    ...
    const instance: ChildPublicInstance = { getCropper };
    context.expose(instance);
    return () => ...
  }
```

The instance exposed by `expose` is type-unsafe and needs to be typed manually, e.g.:

```
const child = ref<ComponentPublicInstance<{}, ChildPublicInstance>>();

child.value?.getCropper()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another mean to do it:

child.ts

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

setup (props, { slots, emit }) {
  const { proxy } = getCurrentInstance();

  // expose public methods
  Object.assign(proxy, {
    method1, method2,
  });
  return {
    // blabla
  }
}
```

child.d.ts

```
export interface Child {
  method1: Function;
  method2: Function;
}
```

parent.ts

```
<template>
 <child-node ref="child"></child-node>
</template>

<script>
export default defineComponent({
  setup(){
    const child =ref<Child>(null)
    
    // call child method
    child.value?.method1()
    child.value?.method2()

    return { child }
  }

})
</script>
```